# How can I set the material properties of a .wrl object exported from PyMol from inside Blender?

Tags: rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I am starting out with a simple scene involving an antibody in blender. The antibody has three separate segments, each represented as a separate object, each of which I want in a different color, as shown below in the 3D view.

[image]

[image]

I did this by setting up a simple material for each one using red, green, and blue. In the 3D view it looks fine. When rendered, they are all green. Why?

The protein model was exported from PyMol using a PDB file to generate the structure. From there it was exported to .wrl and imported into Blender using the PDB import plugin. In PyMol it is shown as being green. I have confirmed that the rendered color is set by the export from PyMol. How can the PyMol export settings be overridden from inside blender?

[image]

Comment: I suggest give Blender 2.8x a try, it's worth it and most likely fixes this issue.

Comment: But I've barely begun climbing the learning curve of 2.7x...